# how to modify argument in function?

Tags: r, function, statistics

I have to solve this:

Modify the cumulative risk calculator of exercise 1 so that the 
argument t has the value 5 if user does not give it any other value. 
cumulative risk = 1-exp(-1/10000*t).

where the exercise 1 was 
We can estimate the cumulative risk of an certain event using the 
exponential formula 1-exp(-1/10000*t) where t is the time to the 
event. Create a function ans(t), which returns the risk at time t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a variable as 5, then call the function using that variable, and save the result somewhere, i.e.

```
function.exp <- function(t) {
  answer <- 1 - exp(-1 / 10000 * t)
  return(answer)
}
x = 5 
m <- function.exp(x)
m
```

Result

```
[1] 0.000499875
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

To assign a pre-specified value to `t` you can use

```
function(t=5){
  answer<-1-exp(-1/10000*t)
  return(answer)
}
```

Comment: I have used this command as you mentioned already, but it is still giving wrong answer.

Comment: @HasanSohail What do you mean wrong?

Comment: i have edited the description of question. I am doing a self learning course in R and after solving the exercise, R checks automatically answer. so as the solution you provided, it is saying wrong answer unfortunately.

Comment: @HasanSohail You are not giving us all the information. What is the function from exercise 1? What is input c?

Comment: sorry if i am creating any confusion. Input C is just to press when the answer is ready. This is to check the answer by R .Just ignore the Input C thing and then you might be able to get it

Comment: @HasanSohail I don't see what else could be missing then. This is your answer.

Comment: okay yes it has approved the answer now.

Comment: @HasanSohail Did you figure it out? Where the mistake was?

Comment: yes i was not defining the function name. I used this command  ans<-function(t=5){
  answer<-1-exp(-1/10000*t)
  return(answer)
  }                                           and it solved the question